One-Way Audio on 1:1 call .NET MAUI , Azure Communication Services using Javascript
I'm working on a 1:1 video call using Azure Communication Services (ACS) with a .NET MAUI app. I’ve managed to get video working both ways, but the audio only works one way. The callee can hear the caller, but the caller can't hear the callee. I’ve tried using RemoteAudioStream but still no luck. I have done the permissions part correctly, at least from the .NET MAUI side. I have checked multiple times on the app permissions from the manifest but also from the app details/permissions.
Basically from the output log I don't see any errors:
CallAgent initialized.
main.js:61 Device permissions granted.
main.js:65 Available microphones: Array(3)
main.js:71 Selected microphone: Headset earpiece
main.js:80 Incoming call received.
main.js:85 Notifying user of incoming call.
main.js:127 Call accepted.
main.js:273 Local participant is muted: false
main.js:312 Remote participant added: 8:acs:7fd9cad8-493b-4fd3-9e67-48bd84547a61_00000022-e7e6-7d84-8ed3-....
main.js:315 Remote participant is muted: false
main.js:276 Call state changed to: EarlyMedia
main.js:276 Call state changed to: Connected
main.js:280 Connected label shown.
main.js:336 Remote participant state changed to: Connected
main.js:330 Remote video stream removed

This worked and works fine when I use regular chrome browser or through the desktop, it even worked fine when I was calling from desktop to android, just not mobile to mobile.
I am providing the javascript I am using below
// Import necessary ACS modules
const { CallClient, VideoStreamRenderer, LocalVideoStream } = require('@azure/communication-calling');
const { AzureCommunicationTokenCredential } = require('@azure/communication-common');
const { AzureLogger, setLogLevel } = require("@azure/logger");

// Set the log level and output for debugging purposes
setLogLevel('error'); // Change to 'info' or 'verbose' for more detailed logs during development
AzureLogger.log = (...args) => {
    console.error(...args);
};

// Variables to store ACS objects and call state
let callAgent;
let deviceManager;
let call;
let currentCall;
let localVideoStream;
let localVideoRenderer;
let remoteVideoRenderer;
let isVideoStarted = false; // Track video state

// UI elements
let remoteVideosGallery = document.getElementById('remoteVideosGallery');
let localVideoContainer = document.getElementById('localVideoContainer');
let connectedLabel = document.getElementById('connectedLabel'); // Ensure this element exists in HTML
let localAudioIndicator = document.getElementById('localAudioIndicator'); // Optional: Add this in your HTML

// Extract query parameters
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const token = urlParams.get('token');
const userId = urlParams.get('userId');
const targetId = urlParams.get('targetId');
const role = urlParams.get('role'); 

// Function to select the best microphone
function selectBestMicrophone(mics) {
    // Prefer 'Headset earpiece' if available
    const headset = mics.find(m => m.name.toLowerCase().includes('headset'));
    if (headset) return headset;
    
    // Fallback to 'microphone:default' if available
    const defaultMic = mics.find(m => m.id === 'microphone:default');
    if (defaultMic) return defaultMic;
    
    // Otherwise, return the first available microphone with a valid name
    return mics.find(m => m.name && m.name.trim() !== '') || mics[0];
}

// Function to initialize the Call Agent
async function initializeCallAgent(token, userId, targetId, role) {
    try {
        const credential = new AzureCommunicationTokenCredential(token);
        const callClient = new CallClient();

        callAgent = await callClient.createCallAgent(credential);
        console.log('CallAgent initialized.');

        // Initialize the device manager to access camera and microphone
        deviceManager = await callClient.getDeviceManager();
        await deviceManager.askDevicePermission({ video: true, audio: true });
        console.log('Device permissions granted.');

        // Select the best microphone
        const microphones = await deviceManager.getMicrophones();
        console.log('Available microphones:', microphones);

        let selectedMicrophone = selectBestMicrophone(microphones);

        if (selectedMicrophone) {
            await deviceManager.selectMicrophone(selectedMicrophone);
            console.log(`Selected microphone: ${selectedMicrophone.name || 'Default Microphone'}`);
        } else {
            console.error('No suitable microphone device found.');
            alert('No suitable microphone detected. Please connect a microphone and refresh the page.');
            return;
        }

        // Handle incoming calls
        callAgent.on('incomingCall', async (args) => {
            console.log('Incoming call received.');
            currentCall = args.incomingCall;

            // Notify the user of the incoming call
            setTimeout(async () => {
                console.log('Notifying user of incoming call.');
                alert('Incoming call received. Press OK to accept.');
                await acceptCall(); // Automatically accept the call for testing
            }, 1000);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing CallAgent:', error);
        alert(`Failed to initialize call. Error: ${error.message}`);
    }
}

async function startCall() {
    if (!callAgent) {
        console.error('CallAgent is not initialized.');
        alert('CallAgent is not initialized.');
        return;
    }

    try {
        const targetUser = { communicationUserId: targetId };
        const callOptions = {
            audioOptions: { muted: false },  // Start with audio, no video
            // videoOptions: { localVideoStreams: [] } // Uncomment if starting without video
        };

        call = callAgent.startCall([targetUser], callOptions);
        console.log('Call initiated.');
        setupCall(call);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting call:', error);
        alert('Failed to start call. Please check the console for more details.');
    }
}

async function acceptCall() {
    if (currentCall) {
        try {
            const callOptions = {
                audioOptions: { muted: false },  // Start with audio
                // videoOptions: { localVideoStreams: [] } // Uncomment if accepting without video
            };
            call = await currentCall.accept(callOptions);
            console.log('Call accepted.');
            setupCall(call);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error accepting call:', error);
            alert('Failed to accept the call.');
        }
    } else {
        console.error('No incoming call to accept.');
    }
}

async function declineCall() {
    if (currentCall) {
        try {
            await currentCall.reject();
            console.log('Call declined.');
            currentCall = null;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error declining call:', error);
            alert('Failed to decline the call.');
        }
    }
}

async function hangUpCall() {
    if (call) {
        try {
            await call.hangUp();
            console.log('Call hung up.');
            call = null;
            currentCall = null;
            isVideoStarted = false;  // Reset video state after hang up

            // Clear video containers when the call ends
            clearVideoContainers();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error hanging up call:', error);
            alert('Failed to hang up the call.');
        }
    }
}

// Clear video elements (both local and remote)
function clearVideoContainers() {
    if (localVideoRenderer) {
        localVideoRenderer.dispose();  // Dispose the local video renderer
        localVideoRenderer = null;
        localVideoContainer.hidden = true;
    }

    if (remoteVideoRenderer) {
        remoteVideoRenderer.dispose();  // Dispose the remote video renderer
        remoteVideoRenderer = null;
    }
    
    remoteVideosGallery.innerHTML = ''; // Clear all remote video elements
}

// Start video
async function startVideo() {
    if (!call) {
        console.error('No active call to start video.');
        alert('No active call to start video.');
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (!localVideoStream) {
            localVideoStream = await createLocalVideoStream();
        }

        await call.startVideo(localVideoStream);
        console.log('Video started.');
        await displayLocalVideoStream();
        isVideoStarted = true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting video:', error);
        alert('Failed to start video.');
    }
}

// Stop video
async function stopVideo() {
    if (!call || !isVideoStarted) {
        console.error('No active video to stop.');
        alert('No active video to stop.');
        return;
    }

    try {
        await call.stopVideo(localVideoStream);
        console.log('Video stopped.');
        isVideoStarted = false;

        // Remove local video stream and replace it with a black screen
        if (localVideoRenderer) {
            localVideoRenderer.dispose();
            localVideoRenderer = null;
            localVideoContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'black'; // Black background
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error stopping video:', error);
        alert('Failed to stop video.');
    }
}

// Create local video stream
async function createLocalVideoStream() {
    const cameras = await deviceManager.getCameras();
    if (cameras.length > 0) {
        const camera = cameras[0];
        console.log(`Using camera: ${camera.name || 'Default Camera'}`);
        localVideoStream = new LocalVideoStream(camera);
        return localVideoStream;
    } else {
        console.error('No camera device found.');
        alert('No camera device detected. Please connect a camera and refresh the page.');
        return null;
    }
}

// Display local video stream
async function displayLocalVideoStream() {
    try {
        if (localVideoRenderer) {
            localVideoRenderer.dispose();  // Dispose of existing renderer to prevent duplicates
        }

        if (localVideoStream) {
            localVideoRenderer = new VideoStreamRenderer(localVideoStream);
            const view = await localVideoRenderer.createView();
            localVideoContainer.innerHTML = '';  // Clear any existing video element
            localVideoContainer.appendChild(view.target);
            localVideoContainer.hidden = false;
            console.log('Local video stream rendered.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error displaying local video stream:', error);
        alert('Failed to display local video stream.');
    }
}

// Setup call event listeners
function setupCall(call) {
    currentCall = call;

    console.log(`Local participant is muted: ${call.isMuted}`);

    call.on('stateChanged', () => {
        console.log(`Call state changed to: ${call.state}`);
        if (call.state === 'Connected') {
            if (connectedLabel) {
                connectedLabel.hidden = false;
                console.log('Connected label shown.');
            }
        } else if (call.state === 'Disconnected') {
            if (connectedLabel) {
                connectedLabel.hidden = true;
                console.log('Connected label hidden.');
            }
            call = null;
            clearVideoContainers(); // Ensure media is cleared on disconnect
        }
    });

    call.on('isMutedChanged', () => {
        console.log(`Local participant mute state changed: ${call.isMuted}`);
        if (localAudioIndicator) {
            localAudioIndicator.textContent = call.isMuted ? 'Local Audio: Muted' : 'Local Audio: Unmuted';
        }
    });

    call.remoteParticipants.forEach(remoteParticipant => {
        subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant);
    });

    call.on('remoteParticipantsUpdated', e => {
        e.added.forEach(remoteParticipant => subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant));
        e.removed.forEach(() => console.log('Remote participant removed'));
    });
}

// Subscribe to remote participants and handle video streams
function subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant) {
    const remoteId = remoteParticipant.identifier.communicationUserId || remoteParticipant.identifier.id;
    console.log(`Remote participant added: ${remoteId}`);

    // Log if remote participant is muted
    console.log(`Remote participant is muted: ${remoteParticipant.isMuted}`);

    remoteParticipant.on('isMutedChanged', () => {
        console.log(`Remote participant mute state changed: ${remoteParticipant.isMuted}`);
    });

    remoteParticipant.videoStreams.forEach(remoteVideoStream => {
        subscribeToRemoteVideoStream(remoteVideoStream);
    });

    remoteParticipant.on('videoStreamsUpdated', e => {
        e.added.forEach(remoteVideoStream => {
            subscribeToRemoteVideoStream(remoteVideoStream);
        });
        e.removed.forEach(() => {
            console.log('Remote video stream removed');
        });
    });

    // Handle remote participant state changes
    remoteParticipant.on('stateChanged', () => {
        console.log(`Remote participant state changed to: ${remoteParticipant.state}`);
    });
}

// Subscribe to remote video streams
async function subscribeToRemoteVideoStream(remoteVideoStream) {
    if (remoteVideoStream.isAvailable) {
        await displayRemoteVideoStream(remoteVideoStream);
    }

    remoteVideoStream.on('isAvailableChanged', async () => {
        if (remoteVideoStream.isAvailable) {
            await displayRemoteVideoStream(remoteVideoStream);
        } else {
            console.log('Remote video stream is no longer available.');
        }
    });
}

// Display remote video stream
async function displayRemoteVideoStream(remoteVideoStream) {
    try {
        // Dispose of the previous renderer to prevent duplication
        if (remoteVideoRenderer) {
            remoteVideoRenderer.dispose();
            remoteVideoRenderer = null;
        }

        remoteVideoRenderer = new VideoStreamRenderer(remoteVideoStream);
        const view = await remoteVideoRenderer.createView();
        remoteVideosGallery.innerHTML = '';  // Clear existing video elements
        remoteVideosGallery.appendChild(view.target);
        console.log('Remote video stream rendered.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error rendering remote video stream:', error);
        alert('Failed to render remote video stream.');
    }
}

// Initialize Call Agent with extracted parameters
initializeCallAgent(token, userId, targetId, role);

// Expose functions to be callable from MAUI WebView
window.startCall = startCall;
window.hangUpCall = hangUpCall;
window.startVideo = startVideo;
window.stopVideo = stopVideo;
window.acceptCall = acceptCall;
window.declineCall = declineCall;
window.toggleMute = toggleMute;

window.isReady = true;  // Flag to notify MAUI WebView that the script is ready

// For testing in a browser environment
console.log('Script is ready.');

// Toggle Mute Function
let isMuted = false;

// Toggle mute state
async function toggleMute() {
    if (!call) {
        console.error('No active call to toggle mute.');
        alert('No active call to toggle mute.');
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (isMuted) {
            await call.unmute();
            console.log('Unmuted.');
        } else {
            await call.mute();
            console.log('Muted.');
        }
        isMuted = !isMuted;

        // Optionally, update local audio indicator
        if (localAudioIndicator) {
            localAudioIndicator.textContent = isMuted ? 'Local Audio: Muted' : 'Local Audio: Unmuted';
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error toggling mute:', error);
        alert('Failed to toggle mute.');
    }
}


Also once it did work amphidromously and the call was perfect, but without changing anything just by re-running it, it started being one-way call again!
I appreciate any heads-up, help or critique, I am new on this .NET MAUI and I like it so far!
Thank you for your time.
I attempted a 1:1 video call using Azure Communication Services. I implemented remoteAudioStream.getMediaStream() for audio and subscribed to remote participants, but audio is one-way; callee hears the caller, but the caller cannot hear the callee. Tried selecting microphones and speakers with deviceManager, checked mute states, and handled audio streams with audioStreamsUpdated events. Expected two-way audio.
Also troubleshooted:

Microphone Selection: The application might not be using the correct microphone.
Participant Subscription: There could be issues with subscribing to remote participants correctly.
Mute States: One of the participants might be muted unintentionally.
Device Permissions: Permissions for microphone access might not be properly granted.
Audio Device Management: The application might not be selecting or managing audio devices correctly.

I am also running it on HTTPS using legitimate SSL

.NET MAUI apps need platform-specific permission handling for Android and iOS. check all the necessary permissions are being requested at runtime, particularly for newer versions of Android require explicit permission for microphone access beyond what’s defined in AndroidManifest.xml.

After multiple days running back and forth, it seems calling the functions manually (example: simple html button) makes the functions work fine. Calling them exactly as they are but through EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(functionname) is creating those complications. I will search further and update when I find something.
-Edit: Permissions were handled correctly, checked long before posting this, thank you for the reply though!

After a lot of back and forth with this code, there are a lot of things to troubleshoot to make sure it's playing:

Audio Media Playback security issue from Google (since I am using a Chrome-based browser): Autoplay policies.
Multiple WebViews: Ensure your WebView is instance-based.
Token Usage: Make sure the token is one-time use only. Don’t reuse the same token, or you might have audio issues.
Device Permissions: Even if you are setting them correctly in .NET MAUI, ensure you have some fail-safe code.
Reset Variables: Make sure you reset variables after every call or failed call.
Unmute by Default: Ensure both users are unmuted by default.
Subscribe to the Other User Correctly.
Don’t Manually Subscribe to Audio: ACS SDK handles this well by itself; meddling with it can cause issues.

FIXES (for each one of the above):
1. Introduce user gesture buttons. Since you are starting and accepting a call, each user should have the corresponding buttons to ensure a user gesture has been given, avoiding autoplay policy issues.
Example:
startCallButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    // Enter code here, such as initiating a call
    call = callAgent.startCall([targetUser], callOptions);
});

Or for acceptCallButton:
acceptCallButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    // Unlock the audio context
    try {
        const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 1, 22050);
        source.connect(audioContext.destination);
        source.start(0);
        if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
            await audioContext.resume();
        }
        console.log('Audio context unlocked.');
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error unlocking audio context:', e);
    }

    // Proceed to accept the call
    await acceptCall();
    notifyMAUICallAccepted();
    acceptCallButton.style.display = 'none'; // Hide button after accepting
});

2. Single Instance WebView.
To manage multiple WebView instances:
if (Instance != null) {
    Console.WriteLine("Attempted to create a second instance of CallPage.");
    return; // Optionally handle as needed
}
Instance = this;

Or, if navigating back to the main page:
public async void NavigateToMainPage() {
    await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () => {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    });
}

3. Token Disposal
Ensure the token is used once by disposing of the CallAgent before reinitializing:
if (callAgent) {
    await callAgent.dispose();
    console.log('Existing CallAgent disposed.');
}

4. Device Permissions in .NET MAUI
For iOS:
if (CallWebView.Handler != null) {
    var iosWebView = (WKWebView)((IWebViewHandler)CallWebView.Handler).PlatformView;
    iosWebView.UIDelegate = new CustomWKUIDelegate();
    iosWebView.Configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
    iosWebView.Configuration.MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.None;
}

For Android:
if (CallWebView.Handler != null) {
    var androidWebView = (Android.Webkit.WebView)((IWebViewHandler)CallWebView.Handler).PlatformView;
    androidWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    androidWebView.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
    androidWebView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
    androidWebView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
}

5. Variable Resetting.
Create a function to reset all call-related variables after each call.
6. Unmute by Default
Ensure users are unmuted when initiating a call:
const callOptions = {
    audioOptions: { muted: false },
};

call = callAgent.startCall([targetUser], callOptions);
if (call.isMuted) {
    await call.unmute();
    console.log('Call unmuted after accept.');
}

7. Subscribe to Remote Participant
Subscribe to remote participants and handle their video streams:
function subscribeToRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant) {
    console.log(`Remote participant added: ${remoteParticipant.identifier.id}`);

    remoteParticipant.on('isMutedChanged', () => {
        console.log(`Remote participant mute state changed: ${remoteParticipant.isMuted}`);
    });

    remoteParticipant.videoStreams.forEach(remoteVideoStream => {
        subscribeToRemoteVideoStream(remoteVideoStream);
    });

    remoteParticipant.on('stateChanged', () => {
        console.log(`Remote participant state changed to: ${remoteParticipant.state}`);
    });
}

Hopefully, this helps! Thank you for your time.


Microphone Selection: The application might not be using the correct microphone.

You mentioned microphone selection, but speaker selection can also cause one-way audio issues. Check that you explicitly select the correct audio output device. Depending on the platform, you need to manually set the speaker to check it's routing the audio to the correct device (headphone, phone speaker, etc.)
const speakers = await deviceManager.getSpeakers();
const selectedSpeaker = speakers.find(speaker => speaker.name.includes('desired speaker'));
if (selectedSpeaker) {
  await deviceManager.selectSpeaker(selectedSpeaker);
  console.log(`Selected speaker: ${selectedSpeaker.name}`);
}


If you're using remoteAudioStream.getMediaStream() for the audio, make sure the remote stream is actually being played by creating an audio element dynamically and attaching the media stream to it.

async function playRemoteAudio(remoteAudioStream) {
  const mediaStream = await remoteAudioStream.getMediaStream();
  const audioElement = new Audio();
  audioElement.srcObject = mediaStream;
  audioElement.play().catch(error => {
    console.error('Error playing remote audio:', error);
  });
}

// Subscribe to remote participant and play audio when available
remoteParticipant.on('audioStreamsUpdated', (e) => {
  e.added.forEach(remoteAudioStream => {
    playRemoteAudio(remoteAudioStream);
  });
});

Here, we are logging for both the caller and callee sides, and tracking microphone and speaker selection, participant subscriptions, and audio stream status. please check the below log data.
Console Logs:
[INFO] Initializing call setup...
[INFO] Fetching available microphones...
[INFO] Available microphones: 
    - Built-in Microphone
    - External USB Microphone
[INFO] Selected Microphone: Built-in Microphone

[INFO] Fetching available speakers...
[INFO] Available speakers: 
    - Built-in Speaker
    - Bluetooth Headphones
[INFO] Selected Speaker: Built-in Speaker

[INFO] Subscribing to remote participant...
[INFO] Participant added: Callee123

[INFO] Audio streams updated for participant Callee123
[INFO] New audio stream detected. Fetching media stream...

[INFO] Playing remote audio...
[INFO] Remote media stream successfully attached to audio element.
[DEBUG] Remote stream active: True
[DEBUG] Playing state: True
[INFO] Audio is playing from remote participant.

[INFO] Call setup complete.

